# Is the process for creating interactive story books different from creating any other apps for ipad?

Tags: xcode, ipad, interactive

I am aware of the process for creating apps for the ipad e.g. xcode, objective-c etc.  Would the process be any different when creating interactive story books such as 'Alice for the ipad' http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gew68Qj5kxw&feature=related, for instance do I need any other software packages other than that specified by Apple http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action?

Answer (score 0):

i think this website should help you with your question http://ask.metafilter.com/158302/How-to-make-an-animated-interactive-storybook-for-the-iPad. it mentions some other programs than the ones in the apple development center such as flash and Jquery.